# Service method OnCreate called twice why?

Tags: android, service

I am making a video player, Starting the service on `onPause()` method of activity. When I kill the app from background/home. The service `onCreate()` method called automatically which is already called earlier with `onStart()` method. 
I am still don't know about the solution but I searched well but didn't find any solution. 
Can anyone help me?

```
 protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                          Log.d("lifecycle", "pause pressed");
    if (!checkServiceRunning(BackgroundPlayService.class)) {
        startVideoBackgroundService();
    }

    if ( mExoPlayerView.getPlayer()!=null) {
        if (activityplayerisplaying && servicebackgroundplaystate) {
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(false);
        } else if (servicebackgroundplaystate) {
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(false);
        } else if (activityplayerisplaying) {
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(true);
        } else {
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }
    }

}
```

and start service method is

```
 public void startVideoBackgroundService() {
    if (servicebackgroundplaystate && mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getPlaybackState() != mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().STATE_ENDED) {
        Intent datasending = new Intent(VideoPlayer.this, BackgroundPlayService.class);
        datasending.putStringArrayListExtra("playlist", playList);
        datasending.putExtra("index", mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getCurrentWindowIndex());
        datasending.putExtra("name", name);
        datasending.putExtra("Activityplyerstate", activityplayerisplaying);
        datasending.putExtra("currentActvityposition", mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getCurrentPosition());
        datasending.putExtra("repeatemode", mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getRepeatMode());
        Log.d("repeatmode", "" + mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getRepeatMode());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(datasending);
        } else {
            startService(datasending);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit of code so we get context on what you are trying to achieve. Although, your service's onCreate() will always be called if you are starting the Service in the Activity's onPause() method. When you try to kill the app, depending on how you are doing it, it goes through onPause() first therefore calling the onCreate() method of your service. This is just logically speaking, a bit of code from you might help me make a better answer

Comment: #T.Mas thank you for your reply i have uploaded some code . My scenerio is to start the service when the activity paused, or destroyed and stop the service when it creates or resumed. Because onPause of activity is calling everytime of leaving the activity in any scenerio so i call start the service there . But now when i kill the app from background / home service stops i am using foreground service.